# Обособление оборота "в случае (чего-то)"

Tags: пунктуация, обстоятельственный-оборот

> В случае возникновения у лица сомнения в достижении покупателем совершеннолетия(,) оно обязано потребовать документ, удостоверяющий его личность.

Comment: Исходя из структуры предложения, я понимаю его так,  что *совершеннолетие* обязано потребовать документ :). Также хотелось бы узнать, у каких других частей тела кроме лица может  возникать сомнение.

Comment: Корректно: *В случае возникновения у лица, непосредственно осуществляющего отпуск алкогольной продукции несовершеннолетним (продавца), сомнения в достижении этим покупателем совершеннолетия продавец вправе потребовать у этого покупателя документ, удостоверяющий личность (в том числе документ, удостоверяющий личность иностранного гражданина или лица без гражданства в Российской Федерации) и позволяющий установить возраст этого покупателя*  (http://народныйвопрос.рф/Home/Article/3104)

Comment: Что-то на инфостиль мало похоже, лучше так: Если продавец сомневается в совершеннолетии покупателя, он обязан потребовать документ, устанавливающий его возраст.

Answer (score 1):

**В случае возникновения у лица сомнения в достижении покупателем совершеннолетия оно обязано потребовать документ, удостоверяющий его личность...**

Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов с производными предлогами является **факультативным,** но обычно они не обособляются **в деловых текстах и в начале предложения.**

В то же время значительно распространенные обороты при отсутствии обособления прочитать  и быстро понять не так просто, поэтому постановка запятой (особенно в менее официальных документах) **ошибкой не будет.**

Эта фраза из Приказа Минпромторга России, стиль канцелярский (три отглагольных существительных следуют одно за другим). Можно, конечно,  написать проще: **В случае сомнения продавца в совершеннолетии покупателя..**

Comment: Отглагольных прилагательных я тут не нашел. Может, они существительные?

Comment: Точно, существительных. Их, наверное, даже четыре. И почти все в рифму, этим чиновникам стихи бы писать.